# Tool to migrate from one git to another git

Tags: git, github

Our project code repository is in Gitlab and want to move to Github. Do we have any tools to migrate complete history,branches and commits?

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: did you ever took a look at: https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/8972566 ?

Comment: Thank you.. later i found https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-move-repository which had step by step instructions..

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to migrate history (branches and commits) and not any wiki or tickets, it's pretty straightforward:

- Clone the original repository
- Push it to the new location

```
git clone --mirror your_old_repository local_directory
cd local_directory
git push --mirror your_new_repository
```

Comment: Thank you @knittl.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool to migrate branches from one repo to another comes preinstalled with git. It's called **git**. You need to add a new remote to your local repo and push the branches to the new remote instead of the old one (origin?). So:

```
git remote add gh https://www.github.com/blahblahblah.git
git fetch gh # just in case
git push gh master develop staging v1.2.4
```

That way you pushed 3 branches and one tag into the brand new gh repo, no real need to go fancy.

If you *later* decided that gh is your new origin, then it's a matter of *renaming* remotes, a different question altogether (even to the point to sneack the change behind git's back by changing the url straight into .git/config ;-)).